# axios interceptors to update auth

Tags: axios, es6-promise

I am using axios interceptors to check auth token on every request. This works fine. But when `accessToken` is null `getToken()` is fired twice. Is there a way to wait for the `getToken` to finish ? I just want `getToken` to fire once. The other requests needing a token should wait until `getToken` is fulfilled.

```
let isAlreadyFetchingAccessTokenRequest = false;
api.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    if (!isAlreadyFetchingAccessTokenRequest && !token) {
      isAlreadyFetchingAccessTokenRequest = true;
      token = await getToken();

      console.log("1. save token to local storage", token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
    }

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to `await` a promise multiple times.
So could try something like this

```
let tokenPromise = null;
api.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    if (!token) {
      if (!tokenPromise) {
        tokenPromise = getToken();
      }
      token = await tokenPromise;

      console.log("1. save token to local storage", token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
    }

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    ...
```

Comment: HI, sorry it doesn't work. `getToken()` still get fired twice. Is it because two concurrent `axios` calls were made at the same time?